# Swift Alamofire list view state

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a list view with some data I am pulling from an API. I'm struggling to understand how to take the data from the API response and putting it into the state for my app to use. Below is the content view in my application that is pulling the data.

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var results = [Bottle]()
  
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
  
    func loadData() {
        let request = AF.request("https://bevy-staging.herokuapp.com")
        request.responseJSON { (data) in
          print(data)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding this to the result block

```
AF.request("https://bevy-staging.herokuapp.com/").responseJSON { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Bottle].self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.results = response
                }
                return
            }
        }
```

However nothing populates in my view and I get the following error.

> nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Why am I receiving this error and how can I get my data to display in the list vew?

Here is the model I am working with.

```
struct Bottle: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var sku: String
    var size: String
    var origination: String
    var varietal: String
    var brand_bottle: String
}
```

Comment: I "get" using AF pre-Combine, but what do you get out of bringing in a third party framework here?

Comment: @Adrian Currently following a tutorial for making requests. I was originally using the baked-in HTTP library but ran into this error. Figured I'd give a third-party framework a shot to see if I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: I haven't bumped into it personally, but it seems like there's a few folks who have encountered it. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665599. Are you going past your guard statement? If not, check the response and see what's in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "?" to model data that can have null data, for all model rows which can obtain "null" need to use "?" or JSONDecoder wouldn't decode data to your model. Inside the model your rows "origination, varietal, brand_bottle" have "String" data type but from the server, you obtain "null", thus JSONDecoder can't recognize data.
You can check responses use services like "http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/" or any other.

[image]

Need to modify model data like below:

```
struct Bottle: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var sku: String
    var size: String
    var origination: String?
    var varietal: String?
    var brand_bottle: String?
}
```

I did recreate your project and all work well code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [Bottle]()
      
        var body: some View {
            List(results, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
    
    func loadData() {
        
        AF.request("https://bevy-staging.herokuapp.com/").responseJSON { response in
                    guard let data = response.data else { return }
                    if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Bottle].self, from: data) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.results = response
                        }
                        return
                    }
                }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Bottle: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var sku: String
    var size: String
    var origination: String?
    var varietal: String?
    var brand_bottle: String?
}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP didn't have optionals in the struct they defined. Did you encounter issues with the endpoint returning nil values? If so, you might want to note that in your answer, as your code differs a bit from his.

Comment: @Adrian Ah gotcha. I was not aware I had to use optionals in my struct. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Trenton Make sure to upvote the person who answered the question :)